# Sync from shared CentOS server to VPS CentOS server

Tags: php, web-services

I have a php/mysql doc management app on shared CentOS server and docs from all clients/users are saved in one folder(not in public_html).

I backed all docs to a VPS box but now would like just to sync difference every hour or so from shared CentOS box to VPS.

How can I do that?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Use a cronjob in combination with **rsync**. rsync is able to transfer diffs of files.

The rsync manpage will tell you how to do so, or any of the many tutorials on the web.

Comment: How can i do that with rsync?